# Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [springSecurityFilterChain]: could not be initialized

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have deployed a war file on WAS server and application is started but while accessing the application . I am getting error.

[31/1/19 22:49:57:909 IST] 000000b6 ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/db/spring-entitymanager.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaVendorAdapter' while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/db/spring-entitymanager.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at

Comment: " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl " well, this seems like a good thing to start with, why is this required class not available, are you missing a library?

Comment: Thanks zack for the response - Trying to figure out why it's not taking the jar file , open jpa jars are there , also hibernet jars also there, that might be a problem ?

Comment: The issue is fixed now though I feel temporarily - the problem was the jar file where the class is available , was not available as part of .war file and the location web-inf / lib - ideally it should be there as part of build as it was available in .m2 dependency. not sure why it is not getting added into war file.. I manually added the jar into web-inf/lib and it worked... any idea why it's not getting added automatically ?